# Cluster Analysis Results Among Data Frame Subsets

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a very large data frame (55497 observations, 553 columns) that I am trying to perform a cluster analysis on. Because of memory constraints, I am forced to subset the data to perform my partition around medoids (PAM) cluster analysis with Gower distances due to having mixed data.

```
Set1 <- df %>% sample_frac(1/3, replace = FALSE)
Set2 <- df %>% anti_join(Set1, by = "id") %>% sample_frac(1/2, replace = FALSE)
Set3 <- df %>% anti_join(Set1, by = "id") %>% anti_join(Set2, by = "id")

library(shipunov)
gdist1 <- Gower.dist(data.x=Set1[, -1], rngs=NULL, KR.corr=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)
gdist2 <- Gower.dist(data.x=Set2[, -1], rngs=NULL, KR.corr=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)
gdist3 <- Gower.dist(data.x=Set3[, -1], rngs=NULL, KR.corr=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)

# ...

pam_fit1 <- pam(gdist1, diss = TRUE, k = 19)
pam_fit2 <- pam(gdist2, diss = TRUE, k = 19)
pam_fit3 <- pam(gdist3, diss = TRUE, k = 19)

Set1$clustering <- pam_fit1$clustering
Set2$clustering <- pam_fit2$clustering
Set3$clustering <- pam_fit3$clustering

df2 <- rbind(Set1, Set2, Set3)
```

I settled on 19 groups using silhouette plots for each of the three sets of results, but in adding back the cluster membership column to the main data, I am a little concerned that the memberships are not ordered in the same fashion across all three sets. For example, I'm concerned that cluster "1" in *pam_fit1$clustering* may actually have a different cluster value in *pam_fit2$clustering* or *pam_fit3$clustering*.

If anyone has any guidance regarding a method to determine which if the cluster labels were calculated similarly or differently across the three subsets, I would greatly appreciate it. I did set a seed at the outset but I need confirmation before I can proceed.

I reconstituted the main data frame with the column value but I cannot discern if there is consistency in the labeling by subset when performing descriptive statistics using other factors that were not a part of the cluster analysis.

I am only intermediately experienced with R so please excuse my lack of knowledge. Thank you all for your time and assistance.